# Dynamical window resizing swt java

Tags: java, dynamic, swt

Here is the result i would like to be able to resize dynamically (sorry for my poor Gimp skills) :
[image]
I looked up the different SWT layout, but none offered what i wanted.
So i splitted my window in canvas, and inserted my different objects onto the canvas.
I know my problem comes from the `.setBounds()`, but i didn't figured a way to place my objects freely which is so easily done.

How can i change my code to have a dynamical window resizing but with a simillar result?

Here a basic example :

```
 public class Main 
 {
  private void images(Canvas Header)
  {
    // in Header Canvas located British flag image
    imgGbFlag = new Label(Header, SWT.NONE);
    imgGbFlag.setBounds(674, 10, 32, 24);
    imgGbFlag.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    imgGbFlag.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Main.class, "/Images/gb.png"));

    // in Header Canvas located German flag image
    imgDeFlag = new Label(Header, SWT.NONE);
    imgDeFlag.setBounds(712, 10, 32, 24);
    imgDeFlag.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    imgDeFlag.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Main.class, "/Images/de.png"));

    // in Header Canvas located French flag image
    imgFrFlag = new Label(Header, SWT.NONE);
    imgFrFlag.setBounds(750, 10, 32, 24);
    imgFrFlag.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    imgFrFlag.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Main.class, "/Images/fr.png"));
   }

   public void Gui(Shell shell)
   { 
     Canvas header = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
     header.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
     header.setBounds(0, 0, 792, 113);
     images(header);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to read this: [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html). **Never** use `.setBounds()` unless absolutely necessary. You can easily create the GUI you want with `GridLayout`s (mind the plural).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FormLayout to have the dynamic resizing, Its the best and easy to use layout for resizing issues.
You need to set layout as formlayout for your shell and Canvas objects so that you can actually decide the position and size of all the widgets in terms of % and not hardcoded.

You have given hardcoded values in your setBounds method, try to avoid them otherwise you will always face resizing issues.

Comment: quite complicated to use in my case, but very helpful.
Thanks ! Now i just need to figure out how to avoid overlapping of the different elements.
Is Canvas helpful for the FormLayout?

Comment: You can use canvas too or a normal composite, it doesn't matter to form layout.

Comment: Generally canvas is used if you want to use painting and GC